\includegraphics not reading \newcommand
Im trying to create a \newcommand which in practice should equal \AAA= 'width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight, page=1, the \newcommand looks something like this:
\newcommand{\AAA}{{width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,page=1}}

But when i use this in the \includegraphic environment \includegraphics[\AAA]{PDF/RS/SRM - Antenna orientation.pdf}
overleaf unfortunately doesn't understand to read \AAA correctly, and ignores it
one solution is to use \expandafter\include\expandafter, but this unfortunately disrupts the useful autofill that is implemented in \includegraphic.
Another solution is:
{\setkeys{Gin}{width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,page=1}
 \includegraphics{1.pdf}}

But this solution is not wanted.
All help is appreciated

That's an expansion issue, you'll need to first expand \AAA before \includegraphics reads its arguments. The following should work:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\AAA{width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,page=1}

\begin{document}
\ExpandArgs{No}\includegraphics[\AAA]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}


that was really helpful, much appreciated!!!

If this answer suits with your requirement, then please accept it by clicking the tick mark

Define your own key.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{AAA}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,page=1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[AAA]{example-image-duck}

\end{document}

